# How to use the pop up permission before accessing the gallery image in android

Tags: java, android

Directly gallery is opening but i want gallery permission before access it.

```
Intent galleryintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
      startActivityForResult(galleryintent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do as like below for checking permission popUp

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          ....      

            if (checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
                Intent galleryintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(galleryintent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }

        }
        //checkpermision
        private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
            int readpermision = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

            if (readpermision != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }

            if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

also add permission in manifiest as below if not added

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I have used this before but directly opening my gallery. No permission pop up is coming. is that problem of  "REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS" ?? because i have used like private static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS= 1;
#yuvrajsinh

Comment: if permission is granted then it will open gallery directly no pop up will shown if there is no permission then only it asks for permission. so at opening gallery get any errors? @Taps

Comment: I have used permission in manifest of "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and now here when i am putting this code in image click directly gallery is opening. But I want pop up instead of direct opening. @yourajsinh

Comment: this pop up will open only if you have not given permission if you granted permission it will not open. for this uninstall apk and install again and check.

Comment: also specify android version of device in which you are running application pop up will show above marshmello @Taps